# SAS X Axis Log Scale

Tags: logging, graph, sas, histogram, scale

I'm using sgplot to create a histogram.

Anyone know how to display the x axis with a log scale?

I have tried to follow the below documentation but it doesnt seem to work.
I get the following warning:

```
NOTE: Log axis cannot support zero or negative values in the data range.
      The axis type will be changed to LINEAR.
```

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=p07m2vpyq75fgan14m6g5pphnwlr.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n10tv33ymilnhln1ld2l0ny0x11u

```
data Have;
call streaminit(12345);
do i = 1 to 10000;
   t = abs(rand("normal", 0, 5));
   x = exp(t);
   y = rand("Normal");
   if abs(x)>1 then output;
end;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
histogram x;
xaxis type=log logbase=10 logstyle=logexpand 
   logvtype=exponent
   min=1 max=8;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider, instead, doing a histogram of the log transform:

```
data plot;
  set have;
  log10x = log10(x);
run;

proc sgplot data=plot;
histogram log10x;

* xaxis type=log logbase=10 logstyle=logexpand 
   logvtype=exponent
   min=1 max=8
  ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Richard,

Thanks for responding, I'll consider the above option.
Any idea if logging the x axis is still possible?